# Read number of drives and its folder & files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make a program to read the total number of drives in system and make list view to show its information that is, counting the number of folders and files individually in each drive present and there is some error due to which I am not able to solve that problem. Please help me in finding the error in the same.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using SystemInformation;
using SystemInformation.Properties;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace SystemInformation
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

                foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives)
                {
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                   var k = Console.WriteLine(drive.Name);
                   item.SubItems.Add(k);

                    foreach (string path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(drive.Name))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(path);
                        lstInfo.Items.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public string k { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some Error? Please Elaborate and tell exact error.

Comment: Actually I am not able to solve the problem. How do I make listview of that.

Comment: Start by reading the documentation for how to work with the `ListView` control [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984139(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the method Console.WriteLine() is void and you can't get an output from it.

You can't do multiple levels using listview. You will need to use TreeView instead.

The following code will give you the file structure on you computer:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives)
        {
            var item = TV_Items.Nodes.Add(drive.Name);
            AddDirectories(item, drive.Name);
        }
    }

    private void AddDirectories(TreeNode parent, string path)
    {
        var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
        foreach (var directory in directories)
        {
            try
            {
                var subItem = parent.Nodes.Add(Path.GetDirectoryName(directory));
                foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(directory))
                {
                    subItem.Nodes.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
                }
                AddDirectories(subItem, directory);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

I didn't understand what do you want to count exactly. Is it the number of folders and files in each folder or just in each drive?